# How to get external URL JSON in Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet

I have problem to get external URL JSON file in my Leaflet JS map. When I try JSON local file, it can run normal, but when I change to external URL from remote server, the doesn't appear.

```html
<body>

    <div id="mapRain" style="height: 95vh;"></div>
    <script>
        var map = L.map('mapRain').setView([-1.4043771, 113.7221155], 7);
        var imageBounds = [
            [-5.247572, 110.593051],
            [-9.563244, 114.948288]
        ];
        var image = null;
        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZGV4dmlscyIsImEiOiJjanhvczU0MnQwYTR2M21vMTJ3MW5kYnRnIn0.9P2ISjrCdk7JLPt72aQQWA', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: '© <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> | © <a href="http://stamet.tjilikriwut.bmkg.go.id/">BMKG Palangka Raya</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(map);

        var planeIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'img/plane.png',

            iconSize: [60, 80],
            iconAnchor: [30, 80],
        });
        $(function() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "data/aviation.json",
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function(result) {
                        var report = result.report;
                        for (i = 0; i < report.length; i++) {
                            var popup = '<strong>' + report[i].icao_id + ' ' + report[i].station_name + '</strong><br>' + report[i].observed_time + ' ' + report[i].time_zone + '<br><img src="img/symbols/' + report[i].symbol + '.png"><br><strong>Cuaca : ' + report[i].weather + '</strong><br><br><strong>Angin</strong><br>Arah (dari) : ' + report[i].wind_direction + '<br>Kecepatan (km/h): ' + report[i].wind_speed + '<br><strong>Jarak penglihatan (km)</strong> : ' + report[i].visibility + '<br><strong>Suhu (°C)</strong> : ' + report[i].temp + '<br><strong>Titik Embun (°C)</strong> : ' + report[i].dew_point + '<br><strong>Tekanan (hPa)</strong> : ' + report[i].pressure;
                            L.marker([report[i].latitude, report[i].longitude], {
                                icon: planeIcon
                            }).addTo(map).bindPopup(popup);
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

When I try change the external URL, the data doesn't appear

```js
$.ajax({
url: "https://juanda.jatim.bmkg.go.id/webkantor/data/aviation.json",
dataType: "JSON",
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stakoverflow Desnug.

Using the remote address it doesn't work because of a CORS policy restriction. If you look at your console you should see an error like `Access ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` or `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response...`. You can [read more about CORS here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Is not a problem of your script or your browser, it's a security measure that browsers have to avoid that website/webapp use unauthorised resources of other remote websites.

Only the webmaster or the server admin of that website can enable the access the resources in Cross Origin Resource Sharing mode.

If I understand your situation, you need to rely to updated data from that website. The only way to do that, is to setup a server-side script (with PHP for example) that download that remote json. Than you can choose if configure it to be run every tot-time (cronjob) or code it like a 'middle service' (e.g. your jQuery script call aviation.php that it downloads and serves the remote json).